# Are DLLs in URLs executed on users local machine or on the remove machine?

Tags: webserver, url

In this question I am referring to DLLs listed in URLs such as this one:

http://survey1.sendyouropinions.com/mrIWeb/mrIWeb.dll

When this kind of URL is navigated to, is the code in the DLL executed on the remote machine (like e.g. a PHP page) or on the users own machine?

Comment: Remote machine.

Comment: Or, more likely, nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is not even clear that there is a DLL involved at all or that no DLL is involved if the URL does not contain the `.dll` suffix. The (remote) webserver just interprets  the URL like it wants and you can not make any definite assumptions on the underlying technology just based on the URL. It would be perfectly possible (but uncommon) to have a URL like `http://example.com/foo.php/bar.dll/foobar.exe/barfoot.gif` which is neither a GIF image, nor is a PHP script, nor a DLL or some executable file but it is instead HTML created by a Perl script. In any case: the server provides the content based on the URL and the browser then renders the content, independent from the text of the URL (the might be cases where the URL text has local affects, like with reflected XSS attacks etc).